# Strange plumbing issue, no water flow to 1 faucet after shutting main off

Tags: plumbing

I have had this happen a few times but was always able to get it flowing again. What happens, after shutting off the main water supply to the house 1 bathroom faucet fails to "prime" for lack of a better term. The hot water side flows fine but the cold water side, nothing. After a day or so the cold water side will flow a bit with the valve slightly open but if you open it all the way the flow stops. Only happens to this one outlet.

I have had it happen in the past and have tried opening all the valves in the house, trying to completely evacuate the system and have got it to work, but I think it was luck....not sure how to do it again.

We are on a slab with overhead galvanized pipe (I know, horrible) if that makes a difference. Seems that this particular line doesn’t prime or something....very puzzling....any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of supply lines feed this faucet? There is a type which has a shutoff valve which closes if the line ruptures. A ruptured line has a higher flow rate and the valve is set to shut under this high flow rate.  One brand is FloodSafe. Sometimes when the water is turned on after a shut off there is a transient flow high enough to shut the valve.

Comment: I will check shut off valve

Comment: Nope...not a valve issue

Comment: Correction....Jim Stewart called it with the supply line, must have grabbed one of those mixed in with the others at the home improvement store...thx Jim

Comment: Was this a "FloodSafe" brand or some other brand? Probably it is still good. I would think that all you would have to do is shut the valve, then flush the toilet, then open the valve a small amount long enough for the supply line to fill with water. I think once the line is full you could open the valve all the way. This type of supply hose has a restriction orifice on the far end which only works if the hose is full of water.

Comment: Caused a partial re-model of the bathroom!....out with the old and in with the new....will be skipping the auto shutoff lines this time

Comment: One resident on our street had a toilet installed and the installer overtightened and cracked the plastic nut or fitting at base of the flush valve assembly. It gave way on  a weekend while the homeowner was away and flooded the house. The damage was extensive, e.g., the lower foot of drywall had to be removed throughout the house.  A Floodsafe supply line would presumably have prevented this. But I don't have them on our two toilets, on our washer, or anywhere else.